# Рекомендации к обоснованию ответа источниками\словарями\правилами и т. д

Tags: обсуждение

Существуют ли уже на Русском Языке SE рекомендации обосновывать ответы по широкой категории ответов "доказательной базой"? Такой доказательной базой могут служить различные словари, справочники по правописанию\пунктуации\стилистике, качественные электронные ресурсы и т. д.

Такая практика [широко распространена в различных сообществах SE](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/174429/383809), особенно тех, где нельзя просто взять, скомпилировать и проверить работает ли. Релевантный пример – [English Language and Usage](https://english.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5/312867).

Формализация такой рекомендации дает возможность быстро указать пост на Мете в комментарии к не слишком качественному ответу.

Разумеется, не каждый вопрос\ответ должен быть обоснован источниками. Особенно, когда объяснение на пальцах четче и понятнее. Или тематика вопроса (метка) такого не подразумевает.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Безусловно, хороший ответ должен содержать обоснования. Оно может быть составлено как минимум двумя способами:

1. Обоснование с опорой на «очевидные» истины. Например, на вопросы типа *Правда ли, что древние арии говорили на русском языке?* можно дать ответ, просто упомянув неясность понятия *древние арии*.
2. Ссылка на источник. Давая ответ, можно сослаться на сайт, книгу, статью, видеоролик и т. п.

Ответы, которые плохо обоснованы, лженаучны или недостаточно полны, обычно удаляются (автор предварительно уведомляется и может дополнить или исправить свой ответ).