# викисловарь не авторитетный источник?

Tags: обсуждение

у моего ответа https://rus.stackexchange.com/a/458195 появилось сообщение

> Want to improve this post? Add citations from reputable sources by
>   editing the post. Posts with unsourced content may be edited or
>   deleted.

не знаю, какая ссылка не понравилась. викисловарь я нашел как [первый результат гугла](https://www.google.com/search?q=%D0%BC%D3%99%D0%BA%D0%B5%D1%80). сейчас проверил, и он [первый также и на яндексе](https://yandex.ru/search/?text=%D0%BC%D3%99%D0%BA%D0%B5%D1%80). эти поисковики вычисляют авторитетность сайтов по количечтву ссылок и другим параметрам. что я ещё могу сделать?

ладно, я переделал ссылку на https://tatar_russian.academic.ru/29783 , там всё-таки есть ссылка на источник. но этот пост всё равно напишу, вдруг кто-то хочет что-то сказать, обсудить.

ещё вместо второй ссылки добавил ссылку на http://bars.org.ru/articles?id=32576 который основан на словаре баранова.

ещё добавил ссылку на этимологический словарь.

ещё убрал текст про персидский.

Comment: несколько дней назад язык того сообщения поменялся на русский.

Answer (score 1):

Я дал ответ в комментариях, продублирую его здесь:

> Уведомление просит вас обосновать возможность («может быть») заимствования из тюркских языков.

Насчет «Викисловаря» — он не авторитетный источник, но иногда полезный, потому что составляется волонтерами, которыми может стать каждый.

Может быть полезно: [Рекомендации к обоснованию ответа источниками\словарями\правилами и т. д](https://rus.meta.stackexchange.com/q/471/178412).

Comment: я тоже написал там, у моего ответа, и копирую сюда:
какой аспект этой возможности нужно написать? нужно написать что тюрки соседи русских, а также сейчас все тюрки россии и многие бывшего ссср знают русский язык? или это считается всем тут известным и писать не надо?
я не могу сказать что-то определённое о (не)возможности перехода мәкер в макар. но я же не утверждаю что это точно так было, и не утверждаю что это наиболее вероятный вариант. на этом сайте нельзя писать орисс и некие гипотезы?

Comment: @qdinar, писать гипотезы можно, но и пользователи должны сразу понимать, что это лишь гипотеза пользователя, а не мнение профессионала.

Comment: @МаркИз ну это, может быть, должно пониматься по дефолту? понятно, что я тут всего лишь пользователь этого сайта. если бы я был неким учёным, я бы наверно сослался на свои статьи в журналах.

Comment: @qdinar эта плашка и служит для того, чтобы пользователи не доверяли слепо информации, она выражает мнение конкретного пользователя, не специалиста в области этимологии и не имеет проверенного научного обоснования. Имя Макар греческого происхождения.